# Show AlertController from TableViewCell, Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I've seen solutions to this problem in Swift. Can anyone help me out?

I have this method in the TableViewController class:

```
- (void)presentAlert {
  UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                            alertControllerWithTitle:@"Flag Content"
                            message:@"Are you sure you want to report this post?"

  UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                           actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                           {
                               NSLog(@"OK action");
                               [cell.feedItem incrementKey:@"flagTotal"];
                               [cell.feedItem saveInBackground];
                               [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
                               [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:cell.flagButton cache:YES];
                               [UIView commitAnimations];
                               // Set flagButton image to checked image
                               [cell.flagButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filledFlagButtonIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                               [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                           }];

[alert addAction:okAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
```

I had hoped to simply call this method from the IBAction in the cell like:

```
- (IBAction)flagTapped:(id)sender {
  _tableView = [[FeedTableViewController alloc] init];
  [_tableView presentAlert];
}
```

Comment: You wants to call an alertview when select a specific row in the table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the right approach of doing this. You can achieve this in two ways. One way is add target action in your cellForRowAtIndexPath and remove - `(IBAction)flagTapped:(id)sender` from your cell class and also remove its action from cell in interface builder as we are doing it programmatically like:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


         [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(presentAlert) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

Another way of achieving this is define a protocol in your cell class. Add this method - (void)presentAlert declaration in that protocol. Set TableViewController as delegate of cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath as.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

             cell.delegate = self;
    }
```

Implementation of flagTapped will be like

```
- (IBAction)flagTapped:(id)sender {
  [self.delegate presentAlert];
}
```

Comment: Using a delegate is the proper approach. You've just left out many of the relevant details.

Comment: I am assuming that this guy already know how to declare a protocol and implementation of delegate. I'll provide further details in case he will require.

Comment: I've successfully implemented the delegate method above however, the animations do not occur.

Comment: add this piece of code in your completion hander UIAlertAction 

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

              // put your animation code here. All your UI changes goes here

      });`

Comment: Like:    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                       [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:cell.flagButton cache:YES];
                                       [UIView commitAnimations];
                                       [cell.flagButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filledFlagButtonIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                                       ;}); ?

Comment: I'm not seeing the animation. Not sure why. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102633/discussion-between-michael-castro-and-shehzad-ali).